# Cross compiling htop libncursesw not found

Tags: raspberry-pi, arm, cross-compilation, ncurses

I'm trying to cross compile htop on an x86 Ubuntu 13.10 machine for Raspberry Pi ARM architecture. I've a crosstool-ng toolchain correctly configured, but when I use the command:

`./configure  CC=/home/fb/crosstool-ng/toolchains/arm-rpi-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-rpi-linux-gnueabihf-gcc CXX=/home/fb/crosstool-ng/toolchains/arm-rpi-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-rpi-linux-gnueabihf-g++ --host=arm-rpi-linux-gnueabihf --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --target=arm-rpi-linux-gnueabihf`

I get this error:

`checking for refresh in -lncursesw... no
configure: error: You may want to use --disable-unicode or install libncursesw.`

If I use the ./configure on the x86 machine, the procedure works, because `libncursesw5` and `libncursesw5-dev` are installed. The same on the Raspberry Pi. If I launch the ./configure then it works.

I tried to specify the location of the libraries with the `LDFLAGS` but I get always the same error.

Where am I supposed to put those libraries?! Or what is the problem when cross compiling?

Comment: any luck with this?

Comment: No. For that purpose I finally moved to ArcLinuxARM that contains always the latest package releases. Cross compiling was really a mess... :-(

Comment: Hmmm... did you put the packages up anywhere?  I was hoping I could add htop to my openelec build without having to figure out how to do builds on it and set aside a week for the compile.

Comment: I didn't upload nothing. Maybe I still have it somewhere on my HD... If so I'll post a link.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can gather, you have x86 compiled `libncursesw5` on the x86 machine and ARM compiled `libncursesw5` on the Rpi.

What you need is ARM compiled `libncursesw5` on the x86 machine.  When you perform the `./configure` command the step you encounter the error on is compiling a small program to link with `libncursesw5` to test for its existence.  You ARM cross compiler cannot link to the x86 library, and this is what causes the error.

You can fix this by putting the `libncurses5w` library from the Rpi onto your x86 cross compile environment, or you can compile `libncursesw5` from source on the x86 machine using the ARM cross compiler.

Comment: Yes, that's right. My problem is that, since I'm new to cross compiling and related arguments, I need to know some things about that.

1) If I decide to use the RPi `libncursesw5` on the x86 machine, which files do I need to get and where should I find them? Where do I have to put them and how can I tell the `./configure` where to look for that files.

2) If instead I compile the `libncursesw5` on the x86 machine for the RPi architecture, I probably will fall on the same problem... so I'll probably need some other RPi compiled dependencies to compile the library...